# error while trying to install and geo fencing in android

Tags: android

I have tried all the search results for `com.google.android`... Package error of "package not found" while trying to run geo-fencing sample code. I have already imported the required `jar` files.

Could anyone help me in solving this issue, with as much detail as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the project "Geofencing" from "https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html" on your current android-workspace of your eclipse.

You will see a bunch of errors in this project, to avoid these errors follow the below instructions:

1. Download the google services from the Window --> Android SDK Manager --> In Extras Folder --> Choose Google play services, Android Support Library --> Click Install Packages.
   In Windows Exlporer, browse to (android bundle folder)\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib.
2. This is a library project. Copy the path to this project.
3. In the Android-Eclipse, import the library project (File --> Import -->Android Folder --> Existing android project into Workspace -->Next button --> Browse to the above selected path --> Check the "Copy project to workspace" --> Click Finish).
4. In the Android-Eclipse, Right click on your project --> Android --> Library --> Click add button --> Select google-play-services_lib --> OK --> You should see a green tick mark with google-play-services_lib --> Apply --> Ok.

By now, your errors should disappear. If not, you need to add support libraries. 
(Right click on your project --> Android Tools --> Add Support Library...).

If the errors doesn't go off,

1. Make sure that both "Geofencing" project and "google_play_services" are in the same work space (to check this, Right click on your project --> Resource --> Check the Location path).
2. Change the android build path, Right click on your project --> Android --> Project Build Target --> Change the check box to a latest version of android displayed on this window).
3. Clean the project and restart the eclipse.